# Efficient way to find who allocates direct memory

Tags: java, memory-leaks, directmemory

I am working on a JAVA project that integrates many components from many teams.

Today, we observe strong direct-memory consumption but we are unable to find where it is allocated.

I am looking for an efficient way (tool) to investigate such a problem

Thank you for your help
Philippe

Comment: The Oracle JVM ships with JVisualVM.  It's a great tool.

Answer (score 4):

On top of my head I remember to use JProfiler or JVisualVM, maybe one of those is an option to you.

JVisualVM is shipped with the Java VM.
JProfiler can be downloaded here: https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html

Comment: Thank you. Thanks to you I discovered a tool that seems very useful (until now, I used to work only with jmc)

I installed the plugin VisualVM-BufferMonitor that provides me a "view" of the direct memory but I can't find anything that would help me to "guess" which components/functions trigger a direct-memory allocation (what would be great for me is to get the call-stack everytime a direct-memory buffer is allocated)